# Монтирование google storage bucket используя gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud

Всем привет.

В /etc/fastab прописано

```
mystorage1 /storage/mystorage1 gcsfuse rw,allow_other,implicit_dirs
mystorage2 /storage/mystorage2 gcsfuse rw,allow_other,implicit_dirs
mystorage3 /storage/mystorage3 gcsfuse rw,allow_other,implicit_dirs
mystorage4 /storage/mystorage4 gcsfuse rw,allow_other,implicit_dirs
```

И с этим проблем нет.

После загрузки файла в сторадж и установки в нем прав доступа *AllUsers* - *ЧТЕНИЕ* (СКРИН), данный файл становится общедоступным, с этим всё ок.

[image: Google Cloud Storage]
Но после редактирования файла с помощью консоли (`nano /storage/mystorage4/news/some.txt`), файл теряет флаг AllUsers, то есть перестает быть общедоступным.

Также и при копировании с помощью  cp /var/www/123/bitrix/blocks/10.1.two_cols_big_img_text_and_text_blocks/preview.jpg /storage/mystorage4/news/ флаг AllUsers отсутствует!

Собственно, возможно, у gcsfuse есть специальный флаг что бы все файлы по умолчанию имели флаг AllUsers?

Либо, как написать правильно скрипт (желательно баш, но позволительно и питон3), который при изменении файлов через консольные редакторы и по фтп будет выполнять примерно такие команды?

```
gsutil -m acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://somestorage/somepic/pic.jpg
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=31536000" gs://somestorage/somepic/pic.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

С правами решилось следующим образом.

[image: Google Cloud Storage]

А вот с Cache-Control пока что не удалось решить.

> Metadata: Cloud Storage FUSE does not transfer metadata along with the
>   file when uploading to Cloud Storage. This means that if you wish to
>   use Cloud Storage FUSE as an uploading tool, you will not be able to
>   set metadata such as content type and acls as you would with other
>   uploading methods. If metadata properties are critical, considering
>   using gsutil, the JSON API or the Google Cloud Platform Console.